# Delphi - Reading a file excluding header information

Tags: file, delphi

in my application i read a file, calculate its **MD5** hash, cypher it with **AES128** and write it inside file comments.

Thats because i need to ensure that file is not manipulated.

Sadly, when i write something inside file's "comments" properties its **MD5** change and my work become useless.

So, i want to read my file excluding file's properties and only then calculate my HASH.
Now i read my file with this function:

```
function MD5File(const FileName: string): string;
var
  IdMD5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  IdMD5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Result := IdMD5.HashStreamAsHex(FS)
  finally
    FS.Free;
    IdMD5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How can i get the "**file properties**" size? i suppose they are on the header OR the footer, so if i know the size i can exclude the first or the last part of the file

edit:
more information: i store the information manually editing the file properties (right click -> properties)
i too suppose that editing those information must not alterate my MD5.. but it does for some reason!
I read the file AND calculate its MD5 with the function in my post.
My problem is that when i write any value inside the comment the file's hash change and i'm writing a string based on file hash.

i think i will just wipe the "comment" properties before calculate hash.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how this file was written in the first place?

Comment: *In general*, additional metadata about a file is *not* stored in the file itself, so your premise is wrong. Some specific file types (like MS Word) support embedded file properties, but for most file types, extra data gets stored in an NTFS *alternative data stream*. Such data is *not* included just from the ordinary opening and reading of a file, so if you're getting that data, then you're either storing it in the wrong place, or reading it differently. Please describe *how* you store the properties.

Comment: You want to hash that part of the file that is not the hash. Fine. Go ahead and do that. What's stopping you? In other words, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan question edited: i just want an HASH that doesn't change when i edit file properties (using windows right click -> properties in details tab), so i must read that file without those properties!

Comment: Well, where are those properties stored? They could be stored anywhere. Only somebody who knows the file format can know that. Since you didn't tell us anything about the file, you cannot expect detailed help.

Comment: well it's just a normal .jpg with the "Comments" field filled inside its properties! I don't think the file extension will change where those information are stored!

Comment: That would be a solution. A better solution is to store the hash somewhere else (not in the file)

Comment: @HypeZ So, where do you think the comments field is stored? And you think that all files have such a field? Where is it stored for a text file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my bad, i didn't realize that jpg only (and maybe some other image format) have EXIF data, even if its pretty obvious! I used to think that all the data inside "properties" was written inside some other file system area and that tricked me

Comment: It's always best to keep your hash separate from the thing that you are hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. The "Comments" data you are entering is stored within the file in the EXIF part of the .JPG file. It does not have a fixed offset, so it's not easy to exclude it from your hash. You'll need to parse the .JPG file and manually skip over the portions of the file that you do not want to include in your hash. Read up on .JPG files and EXIF information stored therein.

Or rethink your premise. If you simply want a hash over the image portion, you can load the image as a TBitMap and iterate over all the pixels in the image (a very slow process) and include their colour code in your hash, thus excluding any data that isn't an actual part of the image itself.

Both these methods will mean that you can't do what you are attempting on anything other than files for which you know the file format (unless they are all image files that you can load into a TBitmap and thus only include the pixels in your hash). You cannot, for example, allow people to change comments or other things in f.ex. Word documents or PDF documents, unless - again - you read the file manually and only calculate a hash over the parts that you don't want to allow people to alter.

Comment: thank you, all makes sense now! i was already using a delphi plugin to write EXIF (CCR-EXIF) but i didn't realize it can change my hash! By the way, i just found that writing empty exif data with that component result in a file with different hash! Now i reached my goal, thank you again :)